# If somebody has logged onto my iCloud account can they see what I buy or download on the App Store?

Tags: icloud

If somebody has logged into my iCloud account can they see what I download?

Comment: Did you use your iCloud Apple ID to buy apps? It's usual, but not required. Assuming they know your password they could check purchase history for that store ID...

Answer (score 2):

**Yes and no** - *not directly*. That person would have to set up iTunes with your Apple ID and then browse through the list of purchased apps.

Comment: A list of the apps purchased and downloaded through the App Store can also be viewed with the iCloud account credentials.